# Laravel Pagination View

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

**Hi everyone, i have done the pagination coding, but the view couldn't call out, can someone guide me ?**
My (categoryController.php) :

```
    // $tmp = Category::all()->toArray();
    $tmp = Category::where('code','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')->where('description','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')->paginate(5);

    $category = array();
    foreach ($tmp as $key => $row) {
        $policy = Category::find($row['parent_id']);

        $tmpResult = new Category();
        $tmpResult->id = $row['id'];
        $tmpResult->code = $row['code'];
        $tmpResult->description = $row['description'];
        $tmpResult->parent_id = $policy['description'];
        $tmpResult->status = $row['status'];
        array_push($category, $tmpResult);
    }

    return view('category.index', compact('category'));
}
```

My index.blade.php :

@foreach($category as $row)

```
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$row['id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['code']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['description']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['parent_id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['status']}}</td>

                    <td><a href="{{action('categoryController@edit', $row['id'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" class="delete_form" action="{{action('categoryController@destroy',$row['id'])}}">
                            {{  csrf_field()    }}
                            {{  method_field('DELETE')}}

                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"  />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
        <div class="container">
            @foreach ($category as $row)
                {{ $row->name }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {!! $category->render() !!}
```

[image: MY error message]

Comment: What should `$category->render()` do? Render the paginator? (Which probably wouldn't work anyway since you're using an `array`, which has no pagination)

Comment: render function is not available on an array. Its only available in a collection. After paginating the result, you are adding them into an array. Thats why you are getting that error.

Comment: but even if im using (  </div>
            <div class="pagination">
                {{ $category->links() }}
            </div> ) this still cannot work for me

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: version 6.5 @lagbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a Paginator in your view. You are iterating the paginator in the Controller and building a new array of new Category instances. You are then passing that array to your view, not the paginated results.

Pass the paginator object to your view. An array doesn't have methods.

---

If you had a relationship setup on Category for `parent` using the `parent_id` you could eager load the description for the parent:

```
$categories = Category::with('parent:id,description')->....->paginate(5);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->parent_id) {
        $category->parent_id = $category->parent->description;
    }
}

return view(..., ['categories' => $categories]);
```

You have adjusted the collection of items in the paginator and are returning the paginator.

If you only want to fix the paginator issue with what you have currently:

```
$categories = Category::where('code','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')
    ->where('description','like','%' .$codeSearch. '%')
    ->paginate(5);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($policy = Category::find($category->parent_id, 'description')) {
        $category->parent_id = $policy->description;
    } 
}

return view('category.index', ['category' => $categories]);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying me. I'm new to laravel and php, can you provide the answer for me since i have tried so many times and didn't find a solution on it

Comment: i have followed your guideline , i think it's working, just a small mistake with this error ( Trying to get property 'description' of non-object ) , how to solve this

Comment: would mean a parent doesn't exist for a category

Comment: Thanks for replying and guide me, much appreciated, but still fail to get expected result =( guess im just so bad

Comment: if a category doesn't have a `parent_id` it is something you will have to check before trying to use the parent ... i updated the code examples

Comment: OMG Thanks , i did it ... omg omg omg , i have spent 3 days on it and finally with ur helps i did it ... Thanks GOD , jesus love u

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $codeSearch = $request->get('code');
    $descriptionSearch = $request->get('description');

    $categories = Category::where('code', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->where('description', 'like', '%' . $codeSearch . '%')
        ->paginate(5);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($policy = Category::find($category->parent_id, 'description')) {
            $category->parent_id = $policy->description;
        }
    }

    return view('category.index', ['category' => $categories]);
}
```